# Browserify/CommonJS with Play Framework

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, browserify, commonjs, sbt-web

I was wondering how to use CommonJS modules with Play Framework 2.3+ ?

I suppose a Browserify plugin can be written in a way similar to sbt-less plugin, but before starting this I want to know how other people are handling this.

Is there already a way for using Browserify within play framework build process ?

Comment: Hi,I'm looking for the same thing, did you find anything in your search.

Comment: I did not find anything, but I have a barely working sketch... I am considering converting it to a plug-in when I have some free time.

Comment: thanks for replaying, I took a different approach I'm trying to separate back-end from front-end now since no need for them to be as the same application, I found it better if they are 2 separate applications, and since the back-end is already a web service API, that's better, reducing the conflicts between the 2 environments, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps somehting like :
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-js-engine or https://github.com/guardian/sbt-grunt-plugin

I'm interrested too, actually I use grunt on a second shell.